# how can i change css path in html helper? cakephp 3.x

Tags: html, path, helper, cakephp-3.0

I want to access admin-css:

```
echo $this->Html->css('adminStyle');
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/adminStyle.css" />
```

But I want this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/admin/css/adminStyle.css" />
```

Can I do it that way?

My webroot folder:

```
 - webroot
   - admin
     - css
     - img
     - js
   - css
   - img
   - js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `echo $this->Html->css('/admin/css/adminStyle.css');`

Comment: Thanks bro. :) You saved me from writing it =>  link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= $this->Url->build('/', true);?>admin/css/adminStyle.css"  type="text/css"/

Answer (score 1):

Update the cssBaseUrl setting in your config/app.php to point to the correct directory ( admin/css/ ).